# How to optimize Sybase Sql query?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sybase

I have one SQL query that fetches data from Sybase database. In the where clause we use text columns based on the requirement `(BU IN ('CMBS','MBS') AND RU='GBR')`. These clauses are killing the performance. The tables used have large number of rows.

Any suggestions to improve performance?

Below is the SQL-

```
SELECT [COLUMN LIST]
from dealer_Key dk, 
INNER JOIN d_posting dp ON dk.deal_key_id = dp.deal_key_id, 
INNER JOIN d_p_v dpv ON dp.posting_id = dpv.posting_id,
INNER JOIN snapInfo s ON dpv.snapshot_start_id = s.snapshot_id, 
INNER JOIN psgl_ratemeter r ON (dp.gl_currency = r.from_currency),
INNER JOIN psgl_ratemeter_value rv (ON r.psgl_rate_id = rv.psgl_rate_id AND rv.refdate = dpv.gl_transaction_effective_date)
where 
r.snapshot_end_id is null
and r.to_currency = 'AUD'
and (dp.snapshot_end_id is null or dp.snapshot_end_id > dpv.snapshot_start_id)
and dpv.gl_transaction_effective_date > '20140930'
and dpv.gl_transaction_effective_date < '20150901'
and gl_business_unit IN ('CTCMB')
and gl_currency='CAD'
and gl_counterparty='IMCLIMTR'
and gl_location='SYD'
and gl_department='LTFSY'
and gl_product='FEES'
```

Comment: Table definition and index info? Also, the whole SELECT would help alot.

Comment: The table is indexed on integer columns. It has clustered indexes. In my SQL we are joining based on the index as well but when we add the where clause on the text columns the performance is degraded.

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  At the very least, it would help other people understand your query and suggest ways to improve it and speed performance.

Comment: My apologies for old style code, my bad . I have updated.

Comment: divide and conquer. Use smaller and multiple queries instead of one big query